# Get the HitTesting result when lots of drawings are in one single visual

Tags: c#, wpf, hittest

So I have drawn some lines on a `Visual Layer` and added it to `Canvas`. Now that I'm trying to HitTest them I'm getting the whole visual. How can I get only the line that I click on?

```
public class MyDrawing : DrawingVisual
{
    public MyDrawing ()
    {
        using (var dc = RenderOpen())
        {
            foreach (var block in blocks)
            {
                // Draw lines here
            }
        }
    }
}

    private void OnMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var x = MousePos.RightDown.X;
        var y = MousePos.RightDown.Y;

        var hitRect = new Rect(x - 2, y - 2, 4, 4);
        VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(MyCanvas, null, MyCallback, 
            new GeometryHitTestParameters(new RectangleGeometry(hitRect)));

        VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(zones, null, MyCallback,
new GeometryHitTestParameters(new RectangleGeometry(hitRect)));
    }

    private static HitTestResultBehavior MyCallback(HitTestResult result)
    {
        // I want to get the line I have hit here
        return HitTestResultBehavior.Stop;
    }
```

Comment: You have store the coordinates of your lines when they are drawn and manually hit test those.

Comment: @TyCobb Isn't there any other elegant way? Some of the lines are polylines as it is difficult this way.

Comment: Looking at the code, you manually drew them. They aren't objects in the visual tree.

Comment: Thanks TyCobb, You mean I can draw them some other way than this?

Comment: You can try using the actual WPF `Polyline`. I am not sure if doing a hit test on it will return true if you hit the line or if you just hit a bounding box containing the line. But you will have to either add in through Xaml or as a child on the control so it can be part of the tree. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polyline(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I need to draw on visual layer for performance reasons.